# Java regex for < and "!" in first line

Tags: java, regex

I use this code to get html source code and the information I wanted. I was just testing if it will return me < and "!" for the first line. However, this doesn't work!

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.regex.*;

    public class url
    {
        public static BufferedReader read(String url) throws Exception {
            return new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    new URL(url).openStream()));
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
            BufferedReader reader = read(args[0]);
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while(line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine(); 
                regex("//<//!",line);
                }
            }   

        public static void regex(String regex, String check){
                Pattern checkregex =Pattern.compile(regex);
                Matcher regexMatcher = checkregex.matcher(check);
                if(regexMatcher.find()==false)
                    return;

                while(regexMatcher.find()){
                    if(regexMatcher.group().length() !=0) {
                        System.out.println(regexMatcher.group().trim());
                    }
                }                   
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I hope that you are aware that regexMatcher.find() consumes the matched string, and therefore the construction if(regexMatcher.find()==false) will consume the first occurrence of the 'regex' in the 'check'. And if check = "regexregex"; then the first occurence will be consumed and System.out.println will print only once(instead of two) times.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you've confused backslashes `\` with forward-slashes `/`. The former are what's used for escaping special characters. So, change this:

```
                regex("//<//!",line);
```

to this:

```
                regex("\\<\\!",line);
```

That said, `<` and `!` don't actually have any special meaning in this context, so you can just write:

```
                regex("<!",line);
```

if you prefer.

Also, note that the above regex matches the two-character substring `<!`. Something about your question makes me think that you might actually be wanting to match the one-character substrings `<` and `!` separately? If so, you can either use the `...|...` syntax for specifying multiple alternative patterns:

```
                regex("<|!",line);   // matches whatever matches < or matches !
```

or the `[...]` syntax for specifying a class of characters:

```
                regex("[<!]",line);  // matches a character that is either < or !
```

(in this circumstance, these two syntaxes are equivalent).

Comment: @user1257428: I see that you've unaccepted my answer. Have you encountered a problem with it?